# how to push the metadata (Ex: name of the file, type of file) from the copy activity to cosomos db container using Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

we have the following ADF pipeline, which is working as expected.

1. Copy Activity which gets data from a S3 bucker and dumps to ADLS

Now

we need the enhance the above, with  File metadata, like a) FileName b) FileType c) CreationDate, being created as a document in AzureCosmosDB, from what we have explored so far, we need to have a in-memory datasource that we need to create, and unfortunately azure data factory does not support this, how doe we acheive this in ADF, without using a custom activity.

IS there a workaround for this scenario ??

Thanks -Nen

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's hard to save file metadata to Cosmos DB in the ADF. You need to achieve this by code. Without using a custom activity, you can use Azure Function activity or create a web application then use web activity to do this.